# Linq get all team members older than 30 when joined

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a query to get all teams with players older than 30 when they joined, I want to return the teamcode of this team(s). The CD is in Dutch but some important things are geboortejaar is year born and jaar_toetreding is year joined. Also ledenId is equal to spelersnr. If some things are unclear, please ask me about it.

[image: cd]

This is what I've tried but it doesn't return anything, it should return one team because there's one team with members older tham 30 when they joined.

```
var team = from t in context.Team
           join wedstrijdspelers in context.Wedstrijdspeler on t.teamcode equals wedstrijdspelers.team.teamcode
           join l in context.Leden on wedstrijdspelers.spelersNr equals l.ledenId
           where SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY",wedstrijdspelers.leden.jaar_toetreding, wedstrijdspelers.leden.geboortejaar) > 30
           select new { t.teamcode};

            foreach (var item in team)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("team: " + item);
            }
```

Declaration of the player, team and wedstrijdspeler. This player was older than 30 when he joined and he's the only person in the team so the query result should be teamcode 03.

```
var kees = new Leden { naam = "Kees", adres = "Kerkstraat 44", geboortejaar = DateTime.Parse("01-02-1971"), geslacht = "m", jaar_toetreding = DateTime.Parse("05-01-2014") };

var team3= new Team {teamcode=03, trainer=lid2};

var wedstrijdspeler = new Wedstrijdspeler { spelersNr = kees.ledenId, bondsNr = 095995, team = team3 };
```

How to fix my query?

Comment: Shouldn't the DatePart of the DateDiff function be "YEAR" instead of "DAY"?

Comment: Doesn't `SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", ...)` only look at the `day` part of the datetime? Since a month only has at most 31 days the chances of finding a difference > 30 are pretty slim.

Comment: Tried it with `YEAR` but the result is the same as with `DAY`

Comment: Oh... `select datediff(year, '2014-01-05', '1971-02-01')` is `-43`; negative value. Won't ever be > 30. -- so it should be `datediff(year, [from], [to])` to get a positive value. -- (also previous statement about "DAY" just looking at the day part is wrong)

Comment: Have you tried [DbFunctions.DiffYears](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220113(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Comment: @Corak switched the two dates and yes it works now ,thanks. Also using `YEAR`